# How to derive the proximal operator for a squared error

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, proximal-operators

To derive the proximal operator of $f=\frac{1}{2} \Vert x \Vert_2^2$:

$\mathbb{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda} \right) x$

following, what is the proximal operator of the squared error $f=\frac{1}{2} \Vert x - x^{true} \Vert_2^2$ ?

The solution that I found is:

$\mathbb{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda} \right) \left(x + x^{True} \right)$

How did they drive that solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $c \in H$, and $f:H \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by $f(x) := \|x-c\|^2/2$. Given $a \in H$, in order to compute $\text{prox}_{\lambda f}(a)$, you must solve the problem

$$
\text{Minimize } \frac{1}{2}\|x-a\|^2+\lambda f(x) \text{ over }x \in H.
$$

The KKT conditions are: $a-x \in \lambda\partial f(x) = \{\lambda (x-c)\}$, from which we get
$$
x=(a+c)/(1+\lambda),
$$
as claimed.

**N.B.:** $\partial f(x) := \{v \in H \mid f(z) \ge f(x)+\langle v,z-x\rangle\,\forall z \in X\}$ denotes the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: With $c = x^\text{true}$ using the notations of the question.


If this case, function $f$ is differentiable, so the KKT conditions of the optimization problem boil down to solving $x - a + \lambda \nabla f(x) = 0$.